# SQL AND is not fetching, Or is not giving proper result

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the simple MS Sql Query iam not able to get results

```
SELECT * FROM tblActivityTracker
WHERE (WoM IN (NULL, 2)) 
AND (DateName = DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()))
```

Pls suggest

Comment: Please Show example data and the expected result and the result you get

Comment: You cannot use `null` with `IN` clause.

Comment: Use `WHERE (WoM IS NULL OR WoM = 2)`

Comment: or.. `WHERE ISNULL(WoM, 2) = 2`  or `WHERE ISNULL(WoM, '2') = '2'` if WoM is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `null` with `IN` clause.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tblActivityTracker
WHERE (WoM IN (2) OR Wom is null) -- or Wom = 2 instead of using IN
AND (DateName = DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()));
```

Comment: Above query fetches Only WoM is Null not WoM is 2

Comment: @user3926897 : Result will be with both Wom having null value and 2

Comment: i wonder why its not fetching if seperately run its coming but i need to combine

Comment: @user3926897 : run like ??

Comment: to simplify its a three condition wom is null, wom is 2, DateName is Monday   ie (DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()))

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tblActivityTracker
WHERE (WoM =2 OR Wom IS NULL) 
AND (DateName = DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()));
```

Or Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tblActivityTracker
WHERE (WoM in('NULL','2'))
AND (DateName = DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do is use isnull

```
SELECT * FROM tblActivityTracker
WHERE isnull(WoM,'') IN ('', '2')
AND DateName = DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions......
Actually below query helped

```
SELECT * FROM tblActivityTracker
WHERE (WoM IN (2)) AND (DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) = DateName) OR
  (WoM IS NULL) AND (DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) = DateName)
```